# Creating a wire break alarm exclusively with surface mounts

Tags: transistors, diodes, components, surface-mount, conversion

Also called wire cut circuits, alarm circuits, etc. Basically a circuit that, when a wire loop is cut sends a signal out like a NO switch being pressed.

I've made them before and it's mostly going well, but I wanted to try making some with exclusively surface mount components. That's gone reasonably well so far as the BOM I've used before is 1x 1N4001, 1x BUZ74, 1x 100K uF @ 25 V capacitor, 1x 10uF @ 25 V capacitor, 2x 100k 1/4 resistors, and 1x 4M7 1/4 resistor.

My question is, essentially: how would I find the diode and transistor in a surface mount variety, or if I can't convert them with replacements directly, how would I go about the value conversions so I can find the replacement diode and transistor?

Comment: Do you *need* a BUZ74, or would some other N-channel MOSFET work just as well?

Comment: That particular part is not necessary. Another with the same function with similar values would work well too. That's just what I've typically used.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for components I find that it's best to search for them at the website of a distributor like Digikey. Most distributors' websites are good at filtering components down to your requirements, and that includes the mounting type (like surface mount). For example, searching for diodes on Digikey allows you to specify surface mount or even the particular package:

[image: Digikey diode search]

Plenty of other parameters (tailored to the component type) are also provided for filtering to help you filter out components that don't meet the specifications that are most important to you. If you're not sure what parameters you need to care about the most, you can just filter down to the specifications which most closely match the component you are trying to replace (e.g. a through hole 1N4001). As a bonus, you can see the current stock so you can judge which component(s) will be easiest to actually acquire -- finding the perfect component does you no good if it isn't in stock anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You start by googling things like "SMD 1N400x" and find this: -

[image]

For the BUZ84 that is rated at 500 volts and 2.4 amps and comes in this package: -

[image]

You should be able to find an SMD equivalent but only if you analyse your circuit and define a set of requirements that will suit an SMD package.

Most other components are available SMD but, is there a highly compelling reason why you can't mix SMD and non-SMD parts (a rhetorical question)?

Comment: I didn't realize you could Google that way and get results. I'd been Googling for quite a bit with various keyword mixtures to try to find the answer until I thought I'd try here.

The reason for only surface mounting is that there is very little space to fit the components and a mixture would be too big to fit. Thanks for the help!